# Laravel main controller return response to page

Tags: laravel

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{

public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    if ( 1 == 1 ) {
      return response()->json([
          'error' => true,
          'message' => 'foo' 
      ], 400);
    }
}
```

I have set up some logic in my main controller __construct method for every pages to extend and I need to return response to page

but I have test this and it is not working, anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: Maybe because the parent construct call is missing? You should do this type of thing with middlewares, not in your Controller constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't return from constructors, you return the response from controller methods.

Create an index method or similar in you main controller and then setup routes through the controllers inheriting from main. This will give you a default shared response.